# Скриптна Bash который удаляет лишних пользователей

Tags: bash, cron, archlinux, users

Хочу написать следующий скрипт:
Написать скрипт на баше, который проверяет список пользователей. Если есть лишние, удаляет в соответствии со списком.
Добавить в крон, сделать запуск каждый день в 2 часа ночи. Проверить добавив лишнего пользователя.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/:.*//' /etc/passwd > file2 #поверяет список всех пользователей в системе на данный момент и записывает их в файл file2

file3 (эталонный список, только те пользователи которые должны быть)
```

Вопрос в том что при работе команда diff выводит первой строкой символы которые указывают где и на кокай строке есть различие между файлами а только потом показывает пользователей которые не входя в список из file3. Как мне избавиться о первой строки в выводе команды diff ?

Думаю что есть избавиться от первой строки в выводе diff, то результат работы команды можно положить в переменную (например переменная R) и удалять лишних пользователей уже следующим образом userdel $R

Быть может есть другое решение как это сделать без diff ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/68684

Comment: Сделайте эталонный файл непосредственно из `/etc/passwd` и проверяйте diff'ом, если файлы отличаются, diff выдаст не нулевой код ошибки, копируйте эталонный файл в `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте эталонный файл непосредственно из /etc/passwd и проверяйте diff'ом, если файлы отличаются, diff выдаст не нулевой код ошибки, копируйте эталонный файл в /etc/passwd.

```
diff -q /etc/passwd file3 || cp file3 /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(comm -3 <(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd |sort) <(sort oldusers.txt)); do userdel -r $i;done
```

в файле `oldusers.txt` список(одно имя на строку) пользователей относительно которого будут происходить проверки, то есть все лишние пользователи из системы будут удаляться

ключ `-r` удалит домашние каталоги если есть